# How to determine link_to path arguments for nested resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

How do I determine the link_to arguments for show, edit, and destroy?  I know "new" is "new_user_post_path".  Nothing else seems to follow this convention though?

My relevant routes.rb snippet:

```
resources :users do
      resources :posts
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running

```
rake routes
```

from your rails root should tell you what you need to know in terms of the name of the routes and the parameters expected.

Comment: So it's just appending "_path" to the route names?  I'm still getting routing errors but I suppose at this point it's not actually a routing issue.

Comment: That's right, if 'rake routes' gives you a named route of new_post then you can use new_post_path or new_post_url.

Comment: I don't think that always applies to rake routes, at least not anymore in rails 3.1, if rake routes gives you: "client_prescription" you need to add an "s" to pluralize prescriptions and then add _path, like this: client_prescriptions_path